# Estoy tratando de resolver esto con Jupyter pero me sale el siguiente error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'M'

Tags: python, jupyter

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data'
datos_np = urlopen(url)
dataset = loadtxt(datos_np, delimiter=",")
print(dataset.shape)
```

---

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         4 url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data'
>         5 datos_np = urlopen(url)
>   ----> 6 dataset = loadtxt(datos_np, delimiter=",")
>         7 print(dataset.shape)
>         8
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py
>   in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows,
>   usecols, unpack, ndmin, encoding)    1099         # converting the
>   data    1100         X = None
>   -> 1101         for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):    1102             if X is None:    1103                 X = np.array(x, dtype)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py
>   in read_data(chunk_size)    1026     1027             # Convert each
>   value according to its column and store
>   -> 1028             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]    1029     1030             # Then pack it
>   according to the dtype's nesting
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py
>   in (.0)    1026     1027             # Convert each value
>   according to its column and store
>   -> 1028             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]    1029     1030             # Then pack it
>   according to the dtype's nesting
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py
>   in floatconv(x)
>       744         if '0x' in x:
>       745             return float.fromhex(x)
>   --> 746         return float(x)
>       747 
>       748     typ = dtype.type

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'M'

Answer (score -1):

Si accedes a la URL que pones en la pregunta verás que obtienes un documento que comienza así:

```
M,0.455,0.365,0.095,0.514,0.2245,0.101,0.15,15
M,0.35,0.265,0.09,0.2255,0.0995,0.0485,0.07,7
F,0.53,0.42,0.135,0.677,0.2565,0.1415,0.21,9
M,0.44,0.365,0.125,0.516,0.2155,0.114,0.155,10
I,0.33,0.255,0.08,0.205,0.0895,0.0395,0.055,7
I,0.425,0.3,0.095,0.3515,0.141,0.0775,0.12,8
```

La primera columna está compuesta por letras, como `M`, `F`, etc. mientras que el resto de columnas son numéricas (flotantes, o un entero en el caso de la última). Intentas cargar estos datos con `numpy.loadtxt`, pero éste espera por defecto que todos los datos sean `float`, y de ahí el error, ya que `"M"` no puede ser interpretado como `float`.

Tienes dos soluciones. O bien le dices a `loadtxt` de qué tipo es cada columna (lo que te obliga también a darle un nombre a cada columna), o en vez de `numpy` usas pandas, que es capaz de "adivinar" por sí solo el tipo de cada columna.

Usando numpy:

```
url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data'
datos_np = urlopen(url)
dataset = loadtxt(datos_np, delimiter = ',',
                  dtype={'names': ('genero', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8'),
                         'formats': ('U1', 'f4', 'f4','f4','f4','f4','f4','f4','i4')})
print(dataset)
```

---

```
array([('M', 0.455, 0.365, 0.095, 0.514 , 0.2245, 0.101 , 0.15 , 15),
       ('M', 0.35 , 0.265, 0.09 , 0.2255, 0.0995, 0.0485, 0.07 ,  7),
       ('F', 0.53 , 0.42 , 0.135, 0.677 , 0.2565, 0.1415, 0.21 ,  9), ...,
       ('M', 0.6  , 0.475, 0.205, 1.176 , 0.5255, 0.2875, 0.308,  9),
       ('F', 0.625, 0.485, 0.15 , 1.0945, 0.531 , 0.261 , 0.296, 10),
       ('M', 0.71 , 0.555, 0.195, 1.9485, 0.9455, 0.3765, 0.495, 12)],
      dtype=[('genero', '<U1'), ('c1', '<f4'), ('c2', '<f4'), ('c3', '<f4'), ('c4', '<f4'), ('c5', '<f4'), ('c6', '<f4'), ('c7', '<f4'), ('c8', '<i4')])
```

Usando Pandas (más simple aún pues no necesitas `urlopen()`):

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data'
dataset = pd.read_csv(url, delimiter=",", header=None)
print(dataset.head())  # Imprime sólo las 5 primeras filas
```

---

```
   0      1      2      3       4       5       6      7   8
0  M  0.455  0.365  0.095  0.5140  0.2245  0.1010  0.150  15
1  M  0.350  0.265  0.090  0.2255  0.0995  0.0485  0.070   7
2  F  0.530  0.420  0.135  0.6770  0.2565  0.1415  0.210   9
3  M  0.440  0.365  0.125  0.5160  0.2155  0.1140  0.155  10
4  I  0.330  0.255  0.080  0.2050  0.0895  0.0395  0.055   7
```

Pandas te simplificará también la manipulación de estos datos. Si no lo conoces creo que puede merecerte la pena aprenderlo.